# Create a new Timer after cancelling

Tags: android

I have a timer that plays a sound at a certain speed (500ms) at a click of a button.

```
final Timer timer = new Timer("Timer", true);

final TimerTask tone = new TimerTask(){
    @Override
    public void run(){   
        sound1.start();
    }
};

Button go = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonGo);

go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(tone, 500, 500); 
    }
});
```

I have another button which stops this timer from playing and theoretically creates another timer so it can be played again.

```
Button stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonStop);

stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        timer.cancel();
        final Timer timer = new Timer("Timer", true);
    }
});
```

After pressing the stop button, the timer successfully stops but I cannot play it again, it crashes the application. Does anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simply the scope of the variable timer. It is declared inside onClick() and you might have trying to access it from outside.